# How to show seperate legend for two geom_col with same aestetics

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to plot overlapping stacked bar charts with the same aestetics and different widths of the bars.

My current solution is by adding separate geom_cols, but the same aestetics. Just different filters on the data set. But this gives the same fill colours two both. I can change this by adding alpha to one of them, which looks OK for me.

The problem here is then, that I still get only one legend for both bars as you can see in the following example:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
  ~status , ~category , ~month , ~value ,
  'plan' , 'A' , 'Jan' , 5000 ,
  'plan' , 'A' , 'Feb' , 4900 ,
  'plan' , 'A' , 'Mar' , 4900 ,
  'plan' , 'B' , 'Jan' , 0 ,
  'plan' , 'B' , 'Feb' , 499 ,
  'plan' , 'B' , 'Mar' , 600 ,
  'actual' , 'A' , 'Jan' , 5200 ,
  'actual' , 'A' , 'Feb' , 4950 ,
  'actual' , 'A' , 'Mar' , 4700 ,
  'actual' , 'B' , 'Jan' , 0 ,
  'actual' , 'B' , 'Feb' , 380 ,
  'actual' , 'B' , 'Mar' , 400
) |>
  mutate(month = factor(month , levels = month.abb[1:3]))

data |>
  ggplot(mapping = ggplot2::aes(x = month , y = value)) +
  geom_col(data = ~ . |> filter(status == 'plan') ,
                    mapping = ggplot2::aes(fill = category) ,
                    alpha = 0.5 ,
                    position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  geom_col(data = ~ . |> filter(status == 'actual') ,
                    mapping = aes(fill = category) ,
                    position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE) ,
                    width = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = 'Category' ,
                             values = c('A' = '#628395' , 'B' = '#95A472') ,
                             labels = c('A' = 'one' , 'B' = 'two'))
```

I can put alpha in the aes() of both bars and add a scale_alpha_manual, this gives an additional legend, but with wrong colours.

So, does anyone have an idea, how I can achieve a similar plot with two legends?

Comment: What's wrong with the colors when adding `alpha=` as an aesthetic? I guess the question may be: what should be in the second legend, if not "actual" and "plan" with two shades of gray with different alpha?

Comment: It doesnt show the - in this example - transparent blue and green, but gray colors with scale_alpha_manual.

Comment: More the point, I think, is that the second legend _is only alpha_, it is agnostic to the `category` itself, so it "should not" be showing colors in its alpha state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fill=` on an "interaction" of status and category.

```r
data |>
  ggplot(mapping = ggplot2::aes(x = month , y = value)) +
  geom_col(data = ~ . |> filter(status == 'plan') ,
                    mapping = ggplot2::aes(fill = interaction(status, category)) ,
                    position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  geom_col(data = ~ . |> filter(status == 'actual') ,
                    mapping = aes(fill = interaction(status, category)) ,
                    position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE) ,
                    width = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = 'Category' ,
                    values = c('actual.A' = '#628395' , 'actual.B' = '#95A472',
                               'plan.A' = '#62839588' , 'plan.B' = '#95A47288') ,
                    labels = c('A' = 'one' , 'B' = 'two'))
```

[image: ggplot using interaction of two fields for fill and alpha]

The labels `actual.A` and such may not be inspiring. All `interaction` is doing is creating a concatenated string collapsed with `.`, so you can create your own new field that combines category and status in a way that you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to show the solution without adding any extra libraries:

```
data$col <- character(1) # better to use dplyr::mutate
data$col[data$category == "A" & data$status == "plan"] <- grDevices::adjustcolor("#628395", 0.5)
data$col[data$category == "A" & data$status == "actual"] <- "#628395"
data$col[data$category == "B" & data$status == "plan"] <- grDevices::adjustcolor("#95A472", 0.5)
data$col[data$category == "B" & data$status == "actual"] <- "#95A472"

data |>
  ggplot(mapping = ggplot2::aes(x = month , y = value, fill = col)) +
  geom_col(data = ~ . |> filter(status == 'plan') ,
           position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  geom_col(data = ~ . |> filter(status == 'actual') ,
           position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE) ,
           width = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_identity(labels = c("A-actual", "A-plan", "B-actual", "B-plan"), name = 'Category'), guide = "legend")
```

This code returns the followin graph:

[image]